# Passenger error: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, mac-osx-server, phusion-passenger, redmine

I installed [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) on MacOSX Server 10.6.8 according to this [installation description](https://gist.github.com/2763243). So far everything works fine: When I start webrick the server serves the Redmine pages. The gems and redmine are installed under the user "redmine".

After that I aimed configuring apache2 with passenger as described [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstallOSXServer). As suggested by the description I also installed the [passenger-pane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane) which stores its virtual host configuration files in `/private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts`. This is what I came up with after a lot of manual try and error. At least, now I can reach a passenger error page.

```conf
// redmine.vhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>    
  ServerName myserver
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/redmine/Sites/redmine"
# RackEnv production
# RackBaseURI /
  RailsEnv production
  RailsBaseURI /
# PassengerUser www-data
# PassengerGroup www-data
  <Directory "/Users/redmine/Sites/redmine">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the passenger module still runs into the following errors.

```
Error message: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb
```

[image: Screenshot of the passenger error page]

The `/var/log/apache2/error_log` of the web server stated the following.

```log
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.12 configured -- 
  resuming normal operations
[ pid=21824 thr=2151905620 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-06-01 18:22:07.126 ]: *** 
  Exception Errno::ENOENT in PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner 
  (No such file or directory - config/environment.rb) (process 21824, 
  thread #<Thread:0x0000010086f2a8>):
```

I experimented with the [user switch functionality of passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengeruser_lt_username_gt) as described in the documentation - as you can tell from my configuration file. Though, I was not successful.

---

**UPDATE:** (04.06.2012)

After I changed the *DocumentRoot* and *Directory* path to `/Users/redmine/Sites/redmine/public` as suggested by Holger the Redmine site is reachable under `http://myserver`. However, it is not reachable under `http://myserver/redmine`; the `404.html` of the `public/` folder is served.
I guess Redmine is reachable under `http://myserver` because I overwrite the *DocumentRoot* for the whole Apache server (?). That is not what I want, though. Without setting the *DocumentRoot* in `redmine.vhost.conf` I encounter the following error page.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to 
use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.12 Server at myserver Port 80
```

**Question:** How must I configure the server to get the desired `http://myserver/redmine` url?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Passenger documentation](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2) you have to use the `public` directory as the document root. In your case this would be `/Users/redmine/Sites/redmine/public`.

That way, only truly public files are in the document root and Passenger finds the correct application root. You should never put any actual code files (or even worse: configuration files) into the document root as they are freely readable by anyone.

Comment: Sounds good. When I change the path the server delivers the `/Users/redmine/Sites/redmine/public/404.html` page. How can I retrieve Redmine instead?

Answer (score 0):

Only for Users, which installed Redmine with the Bitnami-Stack:

I realy wonder, why i got the same Error which described the ThreadOpener after upgrade and restart my OS.
The Distribution also had installed apache and mysql, and start this one.
BitNami has its own apache- & Mysql-Server inside of the Bundle.

Solution:
stop Apache & mysql, and start the BitNami one with:

```
cd /opt/redmine-2.3.1-3
ctlscript.sh start mysql
ctlscript.sh start apache
```

That solve my problem!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to relate to the question.  The OP does not mention using BitNami and his error was that a config file could not be found rather than Apache and MySQL were not running.

Answer (score 0):

To mount as a /redmine URL, try a

```
RewriteBase /redmine/
```

in your VirtualHost